# Show, that there exists a sequence $\left(B_{n}\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of disjoint sets from $\mathcal{E}$

Tags: measure-theory

I am currently trying to solve the following problem.

Let $\mu$ and $v$ be two $\sigma$ -finite measures on a measurable space $(X, \mathcal{E}) .$ Show, that there exists a sequence $\left(B_{n}\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of disjoint sets from $\mathcal{E},$ such that
$$
\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} B_{n}=X, \quad \text { og } \quad \mu\left(B_{n}\right), v\left(B_{n}\right)<\infty \quad \text { for alle } n
$$

Since both $\mu$ and $v$ are $\sigma$-finite measures, I make the sequences $A_n$ where $\mu(A_n)\leq\infty$ and $C_n$ where $v(C_n)\leq\infty$. I then tried to look at the intersection of these, which then is finite with respect to both measures, but I can't be sure that the union is $X$.

If someone has a good idea or hint it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We know that $X$ is measurable. By $\sigma$-finiteness we know that there exists a partition of $X$ into disjoint sets $B^{\mu}_1, B^{\mu}_2 \ldots$ that have finite measure wrt. $\mu$. Similarly, let $B^{\nu}_1, B^{\nu}_2 \ldots$ be a partition of $X$ into disjoint sets that have finite measure wrt. $\nu$. Then $B^{\mu}_1 \cap B^{\nu}_1, B^{\mu}_1 \setminus B^{\nu}_1, B^{\nu}_1 \setminus B^{\mu}_1, B^{\mu}_2 \cap B^{\nu}_2, B^{\mu}_2 \setminus B^{\nu}_2 \ldots$ is a partition of $X$ into disjoint sets that have finite measure wrt. both $\mu$ and $\nu$.

Comment: How can I be sure that $\nu(B_1^\mu \backslash B_1^\nu) < \infty$?

Comment: We have that $\nu(B^{\mu}_1) < \infty$ and $B^{\mu}_1 = (B^{\mu}_1 \cap B^{\nu}_1) \cup (B^{\mu}_1 \setminus B^{\nu}_1)$. Since a measure is countably additive, both $B^{\mu}_1 \cap B^{\nu}_1$ and $B^{\mu}_1 \setminus B^{\nu}_1$ must have finite measure.

Comment: But are we sure that $\nu(B_1^\mu) < \infty$? Isn't $B_1^\mu$ constructed to be finite with respect to the measure $\mu$? And hence we cannot be sure that it is finite with respect to $\nu$